# Simultaneous read/write from SQLIte database using Cordova and Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, cordova

I have an application written for 90% of Cordova(3.5.0) and 10% of Java. This 10% written in Java are used to synchronize the database with an external API. Synchronization occurs in the following way:

```
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        this.checkVersionForInvalidOptionsMenu();
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) 
    {
        Log.d("Execute", "Task");
        return sync();
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
        this.checkVersionForInvalidOptionsMenu();
        if (result)
        {
            Toast.makeText(this.ac.getApplicationContext(), R.string.CURR_SYNC, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            this.notificationProgress.setContentText(this.ac.getString(R.string.notification_complete))
                                     .setProgress(0,0,false)
                                     .setAutoCancel(true);
            this.notificationManage.notify(0, notificationProgress.build());
        }
        closeDB();
    }

    public boolean sync()
    {
        if (!syncInitialData())
            return false;
        return true;
    }

    public boolean syncInitialData()
    {
        String syncData = sfzApi.getInitialData();
        if(syncData != null) 
        {
            try 
            {
                SQLQueries.execSql(db, syncData, this);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I use AsyncTask. Here is the code and the method: `SQLQueries.execSql (db, syncData, this);`

```
public static void execSql(SQLiteDatabase db, String fileName, SyncDatabase task) throws SQLException, IOException
    {
        // TODO: Count lines
        int allLines = 26000;
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        map.put("fileName", fileName);
        map.put("task", task);
        map.put("allLines", allLines);
        afterThirteenAPIVersion(br, db, map);
        br.close();
        removeFile(fileName);
    }

    private static void afterThirteenAPIVersion(BufferedReader br, SQLiteDatabase db, Map<String, Object> map) throws SQLException, IOException
    {
        String line;
        int counter = 0;
        int lastPercent = 0;

        db.beginTransaction();
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            if(line.trim().length() == 0)
                continue;
            SQLiteStatement stmt = db.compileStatement(line);
            stmt.execute();
            stmt.clearBindings();
            stmt.close();
            int percent = (int) ((counter * 100) / ((Integer)map.get("allLines")));
            if (percent != lastPercent)
            {
                ((SyncDatabase)map.get("task")).doProgress(percent);
                lastPercent = percent;
            }

            counter++;
        }
        db.setTransactionSuccessful();
        db.endTransaction();
    }
```

This class makes the whole transaction records sql that came from external api and then executes the transaction.

While I sync I want at the same time to be able to search in the app. I have a field that is used for the search. Here is a sample code which implements part of the functionality behind this field:

```
define([
  'underscore',
  'backbone',
  'sqlinstall',
  'models/schedule/ScheduleModel'
], function(_, Backbone, SqlInstall, ScheduleModel){
  var SchedulesCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: ScheduleModel,

     initialize: function() {
      this.scheduleModel = new ScheduleModel();
      this.db = getDatabase();
    },

    fetch: function(line, typeTransport, callback, direction, stopUid) {
      var self = this;
      this.reset();
      this.db.transaction(function(tx) { 
            self.scheduleModel.getTransport(tx, line, typeTransport, self, callback, direction, stopUid); 
      }, this.errorDB, this.successDB);
    },

    errorDB: function(err) {
      console.log(err);
        if(err.code == 5) {
            new SchedulesCollection().notExistRecord();
            return;
        }
        console.log(err);
    },

    successDB: function() {
    },
  return SchedulesCollection;
});

getTransport: function(tx, line, typeTransport, collection, callback, direction, stopUid) {
      var self = this;
      var typeTransport = getCorrectType(typeTransport);
      var sql = this.sqlDefaultQuery(line, typeTransport);
        tx.executeSql(sql, [], function(tx, result) {
            for (var i=0; i < result.rows.length; i++){
                collection.add({
                    transport: result.rows.item(i).num,
                    typeTransport: convertToHtmlTypeTransport(result.rows.item(i).type_transport_short),
              direction: result.rows.item(i).from_to_stop,
              stopName: result.rows.item(i).name,
              stopUid: result.rows.item(i).uid_stop,
              stopLat: result.rows.item(i).latitude,
              stopLon: result.rows.item(i).longitude,
              schedule: $.parseJSON(result.rows.item(i).time),
                });
            }
        self.addDirections(tx, line, typeTransport, collection, callback, direction);
        callback();
        });
    },
```

When you reach this code would be executed in error and then everything fails. The transaction would be executed but then get problems with the database and it somehow deletes itself.

I tried to make transactions on the part, then runs somewhat, and then in synchronization states that the base is closed and again receives an error that the base is closed.

If you wait for synchronization to complete and then seek no problems. Problem occurs when I try to simultaneously write and read. Since Java only write and read only by cordova (ie by js).

Someone you faced with a similar problem. I use SQLite for Java and Web SQLite for cordova.

If you need more code details will give.